# Replace the nth occurrences of a string within python df after the first instance or use option of groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python df that looks like the below and I would like to replace the nth occurrence of string with space based on the AB column. For example if AB column has AAA and JOb1 is repeated in second row, I'd like to replace that with space.

```
AB  NAME        G_NAME      Status        Last End Time
------------------------------------------------------------
AAA JOb1        Sometext    Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
AAA JOb1        Sometext1   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
BBB JOb1        Sometext2   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
BBB JOb1        Sometext1   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
BBB JOb1        Sometext3   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
```

Expected Output:

```
AB  NAME        G_NAME      Status        Last End Time
------------------------------------------------------------
AAA JOb1        Sometext    Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
AAA             Sometext1   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
BBB JOb1        Sometext2   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
BBB             Sometext1   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
BBB             Sometext3   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
```

I've tried an alternative - that is I've tried using the groupby as shown below, but that doesn't seem to give me my desired output. I might be doing it wrong. Please correct me if that is the case.

```
df['NAME'] = df.groupby(['NAME','G_NAME']).agg([('G_NAME', ', '.join)]).reset_index()
```

Either option would be fine for me. Either using option of replacing next occurrence with space or using the groupby option. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the duplicate rows and replace them:

```
df.loc[df[['AB', 'NAME']].duplicated(), 'NAME'] = ' '
print(df)

    AB  NAME     G_NAME    Status        Last       End  Time
0  AAA  JOb1   Sometext  Ended OK  2020-06-29  10:37:52   NaN
1  AAA        Sometext1  Ended OK  2020-06-29  10:37:52   NaN
2  BBB  JOb1  Sometext2  Ended OK  2020-06-29  10:37:52   NaN
3  BBB        Sometext1  Ended OK  2020-06-29  10:37:52   NaN
4  BBB        Sometext3  Ended OK  2020-06-29  10:37:52   NaN
```